# Generate Numbered MapIcons UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I'm trying to figure out how to generate numbered map icons in C# UWP.
But since I am looping and grabbing Lat and Long values from a database to plot on the map, I need to number the icons so they don't get overwritten (I think).

Can anyone shed some light on this issue for me?
Here is where I am at:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    TargetLat = reader.GetString("lat");
    TargetLon = reader.GetString("lon");
    Uname = reader.GetString("uname");

    //UPDATES THE UI

    BasicGeoposition TargetPosition = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(TargetLat), Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(TargetLon) };
    Geopoint TargetPoint = new Geopoint(TargetPosition);
    // Create a MapIcon.
    MapIcon mapIcon = new MapIcon();
    mapIcon.Location = TargetPoint;
    mapIcon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
    mapIcon.Title = Uname;
    mapIcon.ZIndex = 0;

    // Add the MapIcon to the map.
    MapControl1.MapElements.Add(mapIcon);
}
```

Is there an index or id that I can attach to the mapicon?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not include the number in the Title?

Comment: Well... It looks like it might be working. It doesnt seem like you need to identify each instance of a map icon. They all just appear until you clear them.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to identify each mapicon you generate. It looks like they all appear until you clear() them.